# Unity's Animator.GetBehaviour<T> always returning null

Tags: unity, c#

I have the following line:

[image]

As you can see "transitionOutAnimator" is null before the line runs. transitionOutAnimator is a StateMachineBehaviour of type ThoughtBubbleTransitionOutAnimator.

We can check that the StateMachineBehaviour of the correct type is actually stored in the run time animator:

[image]

Yet when the line runs:

[image]

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Is this a bug? I have another identical instance in the code where I do this, and it works perfectly.

EDIT: Immediate window:

[image]

EDIT: This is still a problem as of Unity 5.3.5f1.

Comment: You don't happen to have another class with the same name do you? Perhaps try including the full namespace path in your type specification. Also +1 for using the debugger to investigate this already.

Comment: @Byte56 Nah, that's not the case unfortunately.

Comment: I'd try it in the immediate window as well. Just to make sure it's getting the behavior from where you think it's supposed to.

Comment: @Byte56 Edited with immediate window output. Is that what you suggested? I've never used the immediate window before.

Comment: Looks more like the method isn't supported via immediate execution, instead of being a lead for what's happening with your code. Next thing I'd try is a rebuild.

Comment: @Byte56 Yeah a rebuild didn't help. I'll try updating to the latest version of Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was causing this issue. The game object that held the animator component was disabled initially. Having the game object enabled initially fixed the issue, and the behaviour reference was able to be accessed through GetBehaviour.

Why Unity does this is unclear to me. If this is intended, then hopefully they reflect it in their documentation in the future, at the least.

Comment: Yet they still haven't documented anything more. I have a null issue as well and my objects are enabled at start.

Comment: The difference being I programmatically set the controller at Runtime.